# Problems while replacing values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

In:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['this should be a pinneapple', 
                              'this should be an apple', 
                              'this should be a tomato', 'this should 3 grapes',
                             'this should be an orange',
                              'this should be an 01',
                             'this should be an 02']})

df
```

Out:

```
    Fruits
0   this should be a pinneapple
1   this should be an apple
2   this should be a tomato
3   this should 3 grapes
4   this should be an orange
5   this should be an 01
6   this should be an 02
```

I would like to replace all the fruits with an id (e.g. `01` to `nn`). For this I tried with pandas replace function:

```
df['Fruits'] = df['Fruits'].replace(['pinneapple', 'apple', 'tomato', 'grapes', 'orange'],\
                                                                      ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'])
```

However, when I do the above assignment nothing is done to the column I am interested to tweak. Thus, how can I replace each word for a predefined number?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parameter `regex=True` in [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Fruits'] = df['Fruits'].replace(['pinneapple', 'apple', 'tomato', 'grapes', 'orange'],\
                                    ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'], regex=True)
print (df)
                 Fruits
0   this should be a 01
1  this should be an 02
2   this should be a 03
3      this should 3 04
4  this should be an 05
5  this should be an 01
6  this should be an 02
```

You can also use `list comprehension` for `codes`:

```
fruits = ['pinneapple', 'apple', 'tomato', 'grapes', 'orange']
codes = [str(i + 1).zfill(2) for i, c in enumerate(fruits)]
print (codes)
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05']

df['Fruits'] = df['Fruits'].replace(fruits,codes, regex=True)
print (df)

                 Fruits
0   this should be a 01
1  this should be an 02
2   this should be a 03
3      this should 3 04
4  this should be an 05
5  this should be an 01
6  this should be an 02
```

Comment: Thanks for the help jez!

Answer (score 1):

try resetting the value using the following:

```
df['Fruits'] =  pd.DataFrame()
```

then assign the new values again